# Return mysqli query result as an array in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I've been searching the internet for a while now, but since I'm new to MySQLi, I cannot solve this problem myself. This is my code so far. I want to return the result as an array.

```
function myFunction($u_id, $mysqli){
   $userinfo = "SELECT email, name, street, placename FROM users WHERE u_id = ? LIMIT 1";
   if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($userinfo)) {
      $stmt->bind_param('i', $u_id);
      $stmt->execute();
      if(!$stmt->execute()) { 
            echo $stmt->error.' in query: '.$userinfo; 
      } else {
        //this is what i found somewhere on the internet, and it gives me an array with the right keys but empty values.
        $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();
        while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) { 
            $var = $field->name; 
            $$var = null; 
            $parameters[$var] = &$$var; 
        } 
        return $parameters;
    }
    $stmt->close();
}}
```

Hopefully someone can help me get this code working, or help me find an alternative.

Comment: check this out http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at using `fetch_array`

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Working from your code

```
function myFunction($u_id, $mysqli){
  $userinfo = "SELECT email, name, street, placename FROM users WHERE u_id = ? LIMIT 1";
  if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($userinfo)) 
  {
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $u_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    if(!$stmt->execute()) 
        { 
            echo $stmt->error.' in query: '.$userinfo; 
        }
    else {
        //this is what i found somewhere on the internet, and it gives me an array with the right keys but empty values.
        $parameters = array();
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
          $parameters[] = $row;
        }
        $stmt->close(); 
        return $parameters;
    }
    $stmt->close();
  }
}
```

Comment: `$parameters($row);` should be `$parameters[] = $row;`

Comment: Thanks all for your help, following the manual's instructions did it for me.